# Display all results queried on PostgreSQL where the JOINING value is missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables on PostgreSQL, namely: **employees** and **employers**.
There is data in each of these tables.

```
Columns in employees: employee_id, employee_name, employer_id.

Columns in employers: employer_id, employer_name.
```

I want to display all *employee_name*'s that don't have an associating *employer_name*.

I used the below query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.employee_name, b.employer_name
    FROM employees a
    NATURAL JOIN employers b
    WHERE a.employee_name LIKE 'Jack';
```

NB!
I have also tried adding in the below to my query:
`COALESCE(b.employer_name, '') = ''`

Problem:
If there is no record in the **employer** table containing the associating *employee_id* value, the query returns nothing all. I am assuming this is because there is nothing for the two tables to join on?... But I would like to at least find all employees that don't have an employer. I would ideally like the *employer_name* value in my result to either return: blank/''/NULL.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use OUTER/RIGHT join. If no records exist from joined table, you will get a join result with null values on the outer/right table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select employees.employee_name ,employers.employer_name
from employees
left join employers 
on employees.employee_id = employees.employee_id
where employers.employer_name is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.employee_name,
       COALESCE(b.employer_name, 'NA') AS employer_name
FROM employees a
LEFT JOIN employers b
    ON a.employer_id = b.employer_id
WHERE b.employer_id IS NULL
```

Your current query has several problems, first of which is that you are using a `NATURAL JOIN`, which should behave link an `INNER JOIN`, discarding employee records which do not match to any employer.  Instead, by using `LEFT JOIN`, we can retain all employee records, regardless of whether or not they have an employer.  The `WHERE` clause checks for `NULL` in the joined table, with `NULL` indicating that the employee did not match to any employer.

Answer (score 0):

Your table name `employees` table is a little odd, IMO. There is a design 'rule of thumb' that says a table models either an entity or the relationship between entities but not both. To demonstrate this oddness, consider the relational operation is

```
employees MINUS employers
```

...which suggests something is off.

Another symptom of this design problem is that the `employer_id` in the `employees` table must have some kind of placeholder to represent the predicate `employee has no employer`, possibly a null (and nulls are to be avoided, IMO).

I suggest you fix this design by introducing a third table to model the relationship between an employee and their employer. Herein lies another design problem: shouldn't this *new* table be named `employees`? In other words, isn't the very definition of an employee a person who has an employer?

Consider this design instead:

```
People: person_id, person_name
Employers: employer_id, employer_name
Employees: employer_id, person_id
```

To find the names of people who are not employees in pseudo-relational notation:

```
People MINUS Employees { person_name }
```

SQL is quite a bit more verbose:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_name
  FROM People
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT person_id FROM People
         EXCEPT
         SELECT person_id FROM Employees ) t;
```

Note your original query needlessly uses range variables `a` and `b`. One of the benefits of `NATURAL JOIN` is the elminiation of duplicate column names. Range variables with `NATURAL JOIN` always looks odd to me!

Comment: Hi @onedaywhen, This was an example, the table names and information I am working with are different, just posted a simply sample. Thank you for your suggestion nonetheless.